# struct elements erasing itself

Tags: c, struct

Ok so I am reading some things from files with this code:

```
for (i=0; i<start;i++)
{
    filename=files[i];  

    if((fp=fopen(filename, "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("unable to open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) !=NULL)
    {
        d[counter].id=atoi(strtok(buffer, del));
        strcpy(buffer2, strtok(NULL, del));
        len=strlen(buffer2);
        if(buffer2[len-1]=='\n')
            buffer2[len-1]='\0';
        strcpy(d[counter].name, buffer2);
        counter++;

    }

    token = strtok (filename, del1);
    holder=token;
    token = strtok (NULL, del1); /* section*/

    token2 = strtok(holder, del2);
    token2 = strtok(NULL, del2); /*course name */

    for(x=z;x<counter;x++)
    {
        d[x].section=atoi(token);
        printf("%d    ", d[x].section);
        strcpy(d[x].course, token2);

        printf("%s    %d    %s    %d\n", d[x].course, d[x].section, d[x].name, d[x].id);
    }
    z=counter;
}
```

Struct definition:

```
struct student {
char course[8];
int section;
char name[19];
int id;

};
```

Everything prints fine except for the "section" in the struct, for some reason the elements makes itself 0 after a certain amount.

Here is the output:

```
1    CSE1325    1    Sally    3233
1    CSE1325    1    George    9473
2    CSE1325    2    Tom    1234   
2    CSE1325    2    Ralph    3540
2    CSE1325    2    Mary    5678
1    CSE2312    1    Tom    1234
1    CSE2312    1    Ralph    3540
1    CSE2312    1    Mary    5678
1    CSE2315    1    Tom    1234
1    CSE2315    1    Ralph    3540
1    CSE2315    1    Mary    5678
2    CSE2315    2    Sally    3233
2    CSE2315    2    George    9473
4    ENGL1301    0    Tom    1234
4    ENGL1301    0    Sally    3233
4    ENGL1301    0    Ralph    3540
4    ENGL1301    0    Mary    5678
4    ENGL1301    0    George    9473
1    HIST1311    0    Tom    1234
1    HIST1311    0    Sally    3233
1    HIST1311    0    Ralph    3540
1    HIST1311    0    Mary    5678
1    HIST1311    0    George    9473
5    MATH1426    0    Sally    3233
5    MATH1426    0    George    9473
```

This is the expected output:

```
1    CSE1325    1    Sally    3233
1    CSE1325    1    George    9473
2    CSE1325    2    Tom    1234   
2    CSE1325    2    Ralph    3540
2    CSE1325    2    Mary    5678
1    CSE2312    1    Tom    1234
1    CSE2312    1    Ralph    3540
1    CSE2312    1    Mary    5678
1    CSE2315    1    Tom    1234
1    CSE2315    1    Ralph    3540
1    CSE2315    1    Mary    5678
2    CSE2315    2    Sally    3233
2    CSE2315    2    George    9473
4    ENGL1301    4    Tom    1234
4    ENGL1301    4    Sally    3233
4    ENGL1301    4    Ralph    3540
4    ENGL1301    4    Mary    5678
4    ENGL1301    4    George    9473
1    HIST1311    1    Tom    1234
1    HIST1311    1    Sally    3233
1    HIST1311    1    Ralph    3540
1    HIST1311    1    Mary    5678
1    HIST1311    1    George    9473
5    MATH1426    5    Sally    3233
5    MATH1426    5    George    9473
```

See how the numbers match?  But for mine it doesn't, when I print `d[x].section` in the for loop as a standalone it prints the correct thing, but when I use it in that combined print statement for some reason it prints out 0 when reaching ENGL1301.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `course` number can be eight characters, and strings in `C` are by convention null-terminated.  Since your declaration is `char course[8]`, when there are eight characters in the course number, the terminating null is being put off the end of `course` which lands in the section number, making it zero.

Declaring `char course[9]` should do the trick.

Comment: Oh, how can I forget something like that >_<  I even dealt with null terminators in the program, but regardless it works just fine now, THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

The `0` is almost certainly the null terminator from this value (and the other values of the same length):

```
"ENGL1301"
```

This 8 character string is 9 characters when you include the null terminator at the end of the string. In this case, the null terminator is being written past the end of the string, which happens to be where the `section` is stored.

To fix this, declare `course` as `char course[9]`